# JS LocalStorage issue

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var fav = document.getElementById("favorite")
var defaultfav = {
   "0": true
}
var favstorage = defaultfav
if (localStorage && localStorage.getItem('favstorage')) {
    favstorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favstorage'));
} else {
favstorage = defaultfav;
localStorage.setItem('favstorage', JSON.stringify(defaultfav));
}
console.log(favstorage);
if(favstorage[id]) {
    fav.innerHTML = "<br><h1>Remove from favorites.</h1>"
    fav.onclick = function() {
    console.log("remove");
    favstorage[id] = false;
    localStorage.setItem("favstore",JSON.stringify(favstorage))
    location.reload()
    }
} else {
    fav.innerHTML = "<br><h1>Add to favorites.</h1>"
    fav.onclick = function() {
    console.log("add");
    favstorage[id] = true;
    localStorage.setItem("favstore",JSON.stringify(favstorage))
    location.reload()
    }
}
```

Hello, above is some code I wrote, I'm aware of it's inefficiencies.
I'm trying to make the button toggle the `dictionary.ID.favorite` value, but I'm having issues.
I've tried printing things and I'm no closer to finding the issue.

Below is a documentation of each variable.

| Name | Type | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fav | HyperLink | The hyperlink, inside it should be a H2. |
| id | Int | The integer position of the "movie" object in my dictionary. |

My dictionary (Imported above the code you see, this works fine for sure)
Thank you for your assistance.
[database.js](https://pastebin.com/raw/UEt2f0Mj)

Comment: I'm not sure why the table doesn't format, it worked fine on the edit page.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @jTorleon This was a mistake I made when copying over the code here. That works fine in the original script, I'll update the code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was setting and reading different keys, hence why the updates didn't change the display.